# I just used 'mv' instead of 'cp' on important files. How do I avoid that in the future?

Tags: centos, files, users

I administer a dataset at my workplace (using Centos 7). The data files for this dataset are in a file structure where everything belongs to 'myuser:group', with write permission allowed only to myuser (aka me) to prevent unfortunate things from happening.

However, today I just went to copy a whole directly of files for a project and I used 'mv' instead of 'cp' on them. While this didn't do anything bad, it certainly alerts me to the possibility that something bad could happen.

The goal is, I want the users of 'group' to be able to 'cp' files out of this directory structure, but not to have write access. These files are already backed up elsewhere, so my goal here is to prevent myself from doing something stupid in the future, not to recover the files in case of stupidity.

I was thinking something along the lines of making root the owner of those files, so I'd have to 'sudo' to do any damage.

**What can I do help prevent myself form accidentally editing/erasing these files?**

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are several things you can do and every approach has it pros and cons.

You can set proper ownership (like you're doing currently), where the user has `rw` (or `r`) access, group has `r`.

You can make the files immutable
 - by modifying the file's attributes you can prevent the file being deleted or modified (but it will be readable, if it has `r` permissions) - `chattr +i file`. If you need to modify the file later, simply disable the `+i` flag with `chattr -i`.

Whichever you choose, you need to strictly follow the policies, workflows and procedures you decide to implement in your organization. They will keep you from doing such .. mistakes.

Comment: you can also remove the write access from the _directory_ itself.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that my solution will help you but it avoids me from doing stupid things.
Open `~/.bashrc` and add this:

```
alias mv="ensure && mv"

ensure() {
    echo Are you sure about that? Type uppercase yes
    read ans
    if [[ $ans = YES ]] ; then
    return 0
    else
    return 1
    fi
}
```

Now you will need to type `YES` every time you want use `mv`.

Comment: And because I am a careless human, I will `yes YES | mv ...`

Comment: By the way you can name your function `mv` and instead of return exit codes to an extra alias you can just perform `mv $@` inside your function.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou thanks! It's something new for me, very good

Answer (score 2):

What about aliasing mv ---> "mv -i" this will cause a prompt anytime you would move a file.

In csh you'd put this into ~/.cshrc:

```
 alias    mv     "mv -i"
```

Comment: in bash this comes as default alias in `.bashrc`